# How to remove line break from LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using this query to import data from a txt file into my table:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '~/Desktop/data.txt' INTO TABLE codes LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (code)
```

This is working fine. But when I take a look in the "code"-field, every entry has a line break at its end. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Load data infile` command is not really suitable for data cleansing, but you may get lucky. First of all, determine what characters exactly make up those 'line breaks'.

It is possible, that the text file uses Windows style line breaks (`\r\n`). In this case use `lines terminated by '\r\n'`. If the line breaks consist of different characters, but are consistent across all lines, then include those in the line terminated by clause.

If the line break characters are inconsistent, then you may have to create a stored procedure or use an external programming language to cleanse your data.